# Google Script Error - Deleting Spam in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I have been using the script below (and have delegated the proper rights to the necessary API) to auto delete SPAM from my gmail account for a while now. I found the script on another Stack Overflow thread that I am not able to comment on, or else I wouldn't be starting a new post.

```
function deleteForever(userID, labelName) {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("in:trash label:junk");
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', threads[i].getId());
  }
}
```

A few days ago (see image), I started getting a "Not Found (line 4, file "Code")" error every time this runs. Like I said, this has been running/working for a number of months, so it's odd to me that now it has stopped working. Anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error?

[image: Apps Script Summary]

Comment: What is on line 4 of yout script file? (if you didn't show us all of your file yet)

Comment: the line that is failing is below. The entire code was pasted in the original post.

Comment: Gmail.Users.Messages.remove('me', threads[i].getId());